# Qiskit ERROR: Circuit contains invalid instructions

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction

Recently I encountered a weird qiskit error which produces a pretty useless traceback. To replicate this error, I create a very simple circuit given below:

[image]

When I run it on a simulator, I get an error whose traceback is at the bottom.

Could anyone point out why this is happening?

The circuit above is produced with the following code:

```
# Importing standard Qiskit libraries
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute, Aer, QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister
from qiskit.compiler import transpile, assemble
from qiskit.tools.jupyter import *
from qiskit.visualization import *

def create_controled_gate():
    h_circuit = QuantumCircuit(1, name='H')
    h_circuit.h(0)
    gate = h_circuit.to_gate().control()
    return gate

circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
controlled_gate = create_controled_gate()
circuit.append(controlled_gate, [0,1])

cr = ClassicalRegister(2,'creg')
circuit.add_register(cr)
circuit.measure(range(2), range(2))
circuit.draw()

aer_sim = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator')
qobj = assemble(circuit, shots=1000)
job = aer_sim.run(qobj)
hist = job.result().get_counts()
print(hist)
```

```
QiskitError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [5], in <module>
      2 qobj = assemble(circuit, shots=1000)
      3 job = aer_sim.run(qobj)
----> 4 hist = job.result().get_counts()
      5 print(hist)

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/result/result.py:269, in Result.get_counts(self, experiment)
    267 dict_list = []
    268 for key in exp_keys:
--> 269     exp = self._get_experiment(key)
    270     try:
    271         header = exp.header.to_dict()

File ~/.pyenv/versions/3.8.7/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qiskit/result/result.py:397, in Result._get_experiment(self, key)
    395 result_status = getattr(self, "status", "Result was not successful")
    396 exp_status = getattr(exp, "status", "Experiment was not successful")
--> 397 raise QiskitError(result_status, ", ", exp_status)

QiskitError: 'ERROR:  [Experiment 0] Circuit circuit-85 contains invalid instructions {"gates": {cH}} for "statevector" method. ,  ERROR: Circuit circuit-85 contains invalid instructions {"gates": {cH}} for "statevector" method.'
```

I use `qiskit 0.22.2`.

P.S. I'm not trying to implement a controlled H gate, but rather understand why this error occurs and how I can avoid it in more complicated scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controlled-H is not one of the basis gates of `AerSimulator`. You can get this list of gates using:

```
aer_sim.configuration().basis_gates
```

So, you need to transpile the circuit into the supported set of gates before running it:

```
from qiskit import transpile

circuit = transpile(circuit, backend=aer_sim)
job = aer_sim.run(circuit)
```

Notes:

- There is no need to call `assemble()`. Actually, passing an assembled qobj directly to the `run()` method of the Aer simulator backends has been deprecated in favor of passing transpiled circuits directly.
- Using `execute()` function also works because `transpile()` is called internally.

Answer (score 1):

I've had better luck using `execute()` rather than `run()`.  I changed the last five lines to:

```
from qiskit import execute

aer_sim = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator')
job = aer_sim.execute(circuit, backend, shots=1000)
hist = job.result().get_counts()
print(hist)
```

and it worked fine.

I wished I knew what was actually causing your problem.  I suspect you've found a bug.  `execute` has all the bells and whistles I need, and seems to be more robust.